# Agora Video Broadcasting Crashing When switching camera

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, agora.io, broadcasting

I used agora's video broadcasting SDK for broadcast functionality in my app. But at the time of switching app crashed.
Error: Thread 24: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1250f0000)

I code for Video broadcasting is following.

```
import UIKit
import AgoraRtcKit
import SendBirdSDK

protocol LiveVCDataSource: NSObjectProtocol {
    func liveVCNeedAgoraKit() -> AgoraRtcEngineKit
    func liveVCNeedSettings() -> Settings
}
//LiveComment
@objc protocol CreateOpenChannelDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc optional func didCreate(_ channel: SBDOpenChannel)
}
@objc protocol OpenChanannelChatDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc optional func didUpdateOpenChannel()
}

class LiveRoomViewController: UIViewController {
    var name = ""
    var imgString = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var img_user: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_name: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var broadcastersView: AGEVideoContainer!
    @IBOutlet weak var placeholderView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var videoMuteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var audioMuteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var beautyEffectButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var sessionButtons: [UIButton]!

    private let beautyOptions: AgoraBeautyOptions = {
        let options = AgoraBeautyOptions()
        options.lighteningContrastLevel = .normal
        options.lighteningLevel = 0.7
        options.smoothnessLevel = 0.5
        options.rednessLevel = 0.1
        return options
    }()

    private var agoraKit: AgoraRtcEngineKit {
        return dataSource!.liveVCNeedAgoraKit()
    }

    private var settings: Settings {
        return dataSource!.liveVCNeedSettings()
    }

    private var isMutedVideo = false {
        didSet {
            // mute local video
            agoraKit.muteLocalVideoStream(isMutedVideo)
            videoMuteButton.isSelected = isMutedVideo
        }
    }

    private var isMutedAudio = false {
        didSet {
            // mute local audio
            agoraKit.muteLocalAudioStream(isMutedAudio)
            audioMuteButton.isSelected = isMutedAudio
        }
    }

    private var isBeautyOn = false {
        didSet {
            // improve local render view
            agoraKit.setBeautyEffectOptions(isBeautyOn,
                                            options: isBeautyOn ? beautyOptions : nil)
            beautyEffectButton.isSelected = isBeautyOn
        }
    }

    private var isSwitchCamera = false {
        didSet {

            agoraKit.switchCamera()

        }
    }

    private var videoSessions = [VideoSession]() {
        didSet {
            placeholderView.isHidden = (videoSessions.count == 0 ? false : true)
            // update render view layout
            updateBroadcastersView()
        }
    }

    private let maxVideoSession = 4

    weak var dataSource: LiveVCDataSource?

    var isOffline:Bool = true


    //LiveComment
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMessageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMessageInnerContainerViewBottomMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtMsgView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMsgViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var sendUserMessageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendFileMessageButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: OpenChanannelChatDelegate?
    weak var createChannelDelegate: CreateOpenChannelDelegate?

    var channels: SBDOpenChannel?

    var keyboardShown: Bool = false
    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var firstKeyboardShown: Bool = true

    var initialLoading: Bool = true
    var stopMeasuringVelocity: Bool = false
    var lastMessageHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var scrollLock: Bool = false
    var lastOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var lastOffsetCapture: TimeInterval = 0
    var isScrollingFast: Bool = false

    var hasPrevious: Bool?
    var minMessageTimestamp: Int64 = Int64.max
    var isLoading: Bool = false

    var messages: [SBDBaseMessage] = []

    var resendableMessages: [String:SBDBaseMessage] = [:]
    var preSendMessages: [String:SBDBaseMessage] = [:]
    var preSendFileData: [String:[String:AnyObject]] = [:]
    var resendableFileData: [String:[String:AnyObject]] = [:]
    var fileTransferProgress: [String:CGFloat] = [:]

    var selectedMessage: SBDBaseMessage?

    var channelUpdated: Bool = false

    var sendingImageVideoMessage: [String: Bool] = [:]
    var loadedImageHash: [String:Int] = [:]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);

        updateButtonsVisiablity()
        print(settings.role)

        if settings.role == .broadcaster {
            txtMsgView.isHidden = true
            inputMsgViewHeight.constant = 0

        } else {
            txtMsgView.isHidden = false
            inputMsgViewHeight.constant = 89
        }

        viewDidLoadAgain()


        self.lbl_name.text = (name.isEmpty) ? UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "isMeUserName") : name

        self.img_user.loadImage(strUrl: (imgString.isEmpty) ? UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "isMeUserAvatar") : imgString)

        loadAgoraKit()

    }

    //MARK: Action Methods
    @objc private func backButtonAction() {
      //  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    //MARK: - ui action
    @IBAction func doSwitchCameraPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.isSwitchCamera = !self.isSwitchCamera
        }


    }

    @IBAction func doBeautyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isBeautyOn.toggle()
    }

    @IBAction func doMuteVideoPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isMutedVideo.toggle()
    }

    @IBAction func doMuteAudioPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isMutedAudio.toggle()
    }

    @IBAction func doLeavePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        APIManager.shared.request(endPoint: .live,
                                  method: .delete,
                                  params: nil) { (result: Result<Success<[String: String]>, Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                if let error = response.data?["error"] {
                    error.toast(.error)
                    return
                }
                self.leaveChannel()
            case .failure(let error):
                error.localizedDescription.toast(.error)
            }
        }

        //leaveChannel()
    }

    func actionSheet() {
        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "User is not live.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            self.leaveChannel()
        }))
        present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

private extension LiveRoomViewController {
    func updateBroadcastersView() {
        // video views layout
        if videoSessions.count == maxVideoSession {
            broadcastersView.reload(level: 0, animated: true)
        } else {
            var rank: Int
            var row: Int

            if videoSessions.count == 0 {
                broadcastersView.removeLayout(level: 0)
                return
            } else if videoSessions.count == 1 {
                rank = 1
                row = 1
            } else if videoSessions.count == 2 {
                rank = 1
                row = 2
            } else {
                rank = 2
                row = Int(ceil(Double(videoSessions.count) / Double(rank)))
            }

            let itemWidth = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(rank)
            let itemHeight = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(row)
            let itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            let layout = AGEVideoLayout(level: 0)
                        .itemSize(.scale(itemSize))

            broadcastersView
                .listCount { [unowned self] (_) -> Int in
                    return self.videoSessions.count
                }.listItem { [unowned self] (index) -> UIView in
                    return self.videoSessions[index.item].hostingView
                }

            broadcastersView.setLayouts([layout], animated: true)
        }
    }

    func updateButtonsVisiablity() {
        guard let sessionButtons = sessionButtons else {
            return
        }

        let isHidden = settings.role == .audience

        for item in sessionButtons {
            item.isHidden = isHidden
        }
    }

    func setIdleTimerActive(_ active: Bool) {
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = !active
    }
}

private extension LiveRoomViewController {
    func getSession(of uid: UInt) -> VideoSession? {
        for session in videoSessions {
            if session.uid == uid {
                return session
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func videoSession(of uid: UInt) -> VideoSession {
        if let fetchedSession = getSession(of: uid) {
            return fetchedSession
        } else {
            let newSession = VideoSession(uid: uid)
            videoSessions.append(newSession)
            return newSession
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Agora Media SDK
private extension LiveRoomViewController {
    func loadAgoraKit() {
        guard let channelId = settings.roomName else {
            return
        }

        setIdleTimerActive(false)

        // Step 1, set delegate to inform the app on AgoraRtcEngineKit events
        agoraKit.delegate = self
        // Step 2, set live broadcasting mode
        // for details: https://docs.agora.io/cn/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/setChannelProfile:
        agoraKit.setChannelProfile(.liveBroadcasting)
        // set client role
        agoraKit.setClientRole(settings.role)

        // Step 3, Warning: only enable dual stream mode if there will be more than one broadcaster in the channel
        agoraKit.enableDualStreamMode(true)

        // Step 4, enable the video module
        agoraKit.enableVideo()
        // set video configuration
        agoraKit.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(
            AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration(
                size: settings.dimension,
                frameRate: settings.frameRate,
                bitrate: AgoraVideoBitrateStandard,
                orientationMode: .adaptative
            )
        )

        // if current role is broadcaster, add local render view and start preview
        if settings.role == .broadcaster {
            addLocalSession()
            agoraKit.startPreview()
        }

        // Step 5, join channel and start group chat
        // If join  channel success, agoraKit triggers it's delegate function
        // 'rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didJoinChannel channel: String, withUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int)'
        agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: KeyCenter.Token, channelId: channelId, info: nil, uid: 0, joinSuccess: nil)

        // Step 6, set speaker audio route
        agoraKit.setEnableSpeakerphone(true)
    }

    func addLocalSession() {
        let localSession = VideoSession.localSession()
        localSession.updateInfo(fps: settings.frameRate.rawValue)
        videoSessions.append(localSession)
        agoraKit.setupLocalVideo(localSession.canvas)
    }

    func leaveChannel() {
        // Step 1, release local AgoraRtcVideoCanvas instance
        agoraKit.setupLocalVideo(nil)
        // Step 2, leave channel and end group chat
        agoraKit.leaveChannel(nil)

        // Step 3, if current role is broadcaster,  stop preview after leave channel
        if settings.role == .broadcaster {
            agoraKit.stopPreview()
        }

        setIdleTimerActive(true)

        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: - AgoraRtcEngineDelegate
extension LiveRoomViewController: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate {

    /// Occurs when the first local video frame is displayed/rendered on the local video view.
    ///
    /// Same as [firstLocalVideoFrameBlock]([AgoraRtcEngineKit firstLocalVideoFrameBlock:]).
    /// @param engine  AgoraRtcEngineKit object.
    /// @param size    Size of the first local video frame (width and height).
    /// @param elapsed Time elapsed (ms) from the local user calling the [joinChannelByToken]([AgoraRtcEngineKit joinChannelByToken:channelId:info:uid:joinSuccess:]) method until the SDK calls this callback.
    ///
    /// If the [startPreview]([AgoraRtcEngineKit startPreview]) method is called before the [joinChannelByToken]([AgoraRtcEngineKit joinChannelByToken:channelId:info:uid:joinSuccess:]) method, then `elapsed` is the time elapsed from calling the [startPreview]([AgoraRtcEngineKit startPreview]) method until the SDK triggers this callback.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, firstLocalVideoFrameWith size: CGSize, elapsed: Int) {
        if let selfSession = videoSessions.first {
            selfSession.updateInfo(resolution: size)
        }
    }

    /// Reports the statistics of the current call. The SDK triggers this callback once every two seconds after the user joins the channel.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, reportRtcStats stats: AgoraChannelStats) {
        if let selfSession = videoSessions.first {
            selfSession.updateChannelStats(stats)
        } else {
            isOffline = false
            if isOffline {
                kb.topMostVC?.startAnimateLoader()
                isOffline = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: {
                    kb.topMostVC?.stopAnimating()
                    self.actionSheet()

                })
            }


        }
    }


    /// Occurs when the first remote video frame is received and decoded.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit object.
    ///   - uid: User ID of the remote user sending the video stream.
    ///   - size: Size of the video frame (width and height).
    ///   - elapsed: Time elapsed (ms) from the local user calling the joinChannelByToken method until the SDK triggers this callback.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, firstRemoteVideoDecodedOfUid uid: UInt, size: CGSize, elapsed: Int) {
        guard videoSessions.count <= maxVideoSession else {
            return
        }

        let userSession = videoSession(of: uid)
        userSession.updateInfo(resolution: size)
        agoraKit.setupRemoteVideo(userSession.canvas)
    }

    /// Occurs when a remote user (Communication)/host (Live Broadcast) leaves a channel. Same as [userOfflineBlock]([AgoraRtcEngineKit userOfflineBlock:]).
    ///
    /// There are two reasons for users to be offline:
    ///
    /// - Leave a channel: When the user/host leaves a channel, the user/host sends a goodbye message. When the message is received, the SDK assumes that the user/host leaves a channel.
    /// - Drop offline: When no data packet of the user or host is received for a certain period of time (20 seconds for the Communication profile, and more for the Live-broadcast profile), the SDK assumes that the user/host drops offline. Unreliable network connections may lead to false detections, so Agora recommends using a signaling system for more reliable offline detection.
    ///
    ///  @param engine AgoraRtcEngineKit object.
    ///  @param uid    ID of the user or host who leaves a channel or goes offline.
    ///  @param reason Reason why the user goes offline, see AgoraUserOfflineReason.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOfflineOfUid uid: UInt, reason: AgoraUserOfflineReason) {
        var indexToDelete: Int?
        for (index, session) in videoSessions.enumerated() where session.uid == uid {
            indexToDelete = index
            break
        }

        if let indexToDelete = indexToDelete {
            let deletedSession = videoSessions.remove(at: indexToDelete)
            deletedSession.hostingView.removeFromSuperview()

            // release canvas's view
            deletedSession.canvas.view = nil
        }
    }

    /// Reports the statistics of the video stream from each remote user/host.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, remoteVideoStats stats: AgoraRtcRemoteVideoStats) {
        if let session = getSession(of: stats.uid) {
            session.updateVideoStats(stats)
        }
    }

    /// Reports the statistics of the audio stream from each remote user/host.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, remoteAudioStats stats: AgoraRtcRemoteAudioStats) {
        if let session = getSession(of: stats.uid) {
            session.updateAudioStats(stats)
        }
    }

    /// Reports a warning during SDK runtime.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOccurWarning warningCode: AgoraWarningCode) {
        print("warning code: \(warningCode.description)")

    }

    /// Reports an error during SDK runtime.
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOccurError errorCode: AgoraErrorCode) {
        print("error code: \(errorCode.description)")
    }
}
```

Please help me out if I did something wrong in it or any suggestion how can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you access `agoraKit` you're actually calling this:

```
dataSource!.liveVCNeedAgoraKit()
```

This involves force unwrapping a weak optional variable. If `dataSource` is `nil`, you'll get the error you're seeing. It's also possible that the error is in the `liveVCNeedAgoraKit()` function, which could be doing similar force unwrapping.

You shouldn't use force unwrapping with delegates/data sources, which might not be set and could go away at any time. Use optional binding instead, with some fallback if the delegate is not set.

```
if let source = dataSource {
    return source.liveVCNeedAgoraKit()
} else {
    // Error handling. Display an alert, return nil, initialize a new agoraKit to return - whatever makes the most sense for your app.
}
```